# Setting up routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I put the following code in my routes config :

```
resources :users do

end
```

I get all the CRUD operations routes. i.e

```
/users/new
/users/:id/edit
```

and so on.

How do I configure routes so I get route like this :

```
/users/lookup/:search_query
```

And when users reaches this routes he/she should be taked to `lookup` method of my controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do :

```
resources :users do
  get :lookup, on: :collection
end
```

And I would pass the `search_query` as a parameter. With that you will be more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

```
resources :users do
  get '/lookup/:search_query' => 'users#lookup', on: :collection
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resources :users do
end

match '/users/lookup/:search_query' => "users#lookup", :as => :user_lookup
```

Comment: Simon's answer is better :-)

Comment: I actually like your way better. Keep resouce CRUD stuff together and custom ones in a different place.